# How to extract and display words from a long list of words from a text string in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-statements

I have a google sheet which contains 2 columns in Sheet 1
Column one contains text strings. I want to extract "job titles"  from those text strings in the next column. List of all jobs title is in another sheet name "Data Lookup"

If any exact match job title (lower case or upper case or in any case) is present in "Data Lookup" sheet and in A1:A1795 range then show in sheet 1 and if exact match is not found then find any partial match job title.

For this purpose I made the tried following custom code.

```
function findtitle(text, list){
  var result = 'Not Found';
  list = list.flat();
  list.forEach( str => {    
    if(text.includes(str)){      
      result = str;      
      return result;    
     }  
  });  
  return result;
}
```

It is finding only partial match words and sometimes it is not finding any word. while job title is present in Data lookup sheet.
i have attached a sample google sheet also
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17AZ2Cuk4gcAiXm_yo3_IK-WeYqO5g7n5HBumCjNknFU/edit?usp=sharing

for example
in sheet 1 cell number A43 contains a text string word " Project manager" and in
Cell no. A470 in Sheet "Data Lookup"  project manager" is present but it is showing only manager.
How to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you please clarify how you call the function, what `text` and `list` look like and an example of the output you're expecting.

Comment: This is the formula in sheet 1 column 2 i am using =findtitle(LOWER(A2),'Data Lookup'!$A$2:$A$1795)

Comment: Did you have time to check the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few of problems with your script.

- Sometimes matches are not exact, for instance you may have extra spaces, as pointed out by Goran, so those matches are missed
- You only return one title per job description, but they often mention several
- Your function only returns one value, so you have to repeat it multiple times for every job description.

I built the following one.

What it does is:

- convert each job title to a regular expression for better matching
- returns multiple job titles per job description
- accepts and returns a range of values

```js
const getJobs = (jobDescriptions, jobs) => {
  const escape = string => string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
  const toRe = str => new RegExp(escape(str).replace(/ +/g, ' +'), 'i');
  return jobDescriptions.map(jd => {
    const result = [
      jobs
        .reduce((acc, job) => {
          const re = toRe(job[0]);
          if (re.test(jd)) acc.push(job[0]);
          return [...new Set(acc)];
        }, [])
        .join(', '),
    ];
    return '' !== result[0] ? result : ['Not Found'];
  });
};
```

I put it in cell `C2` in your sheet, you can check out the result.

Notice you also have duplicates in your `Data Lookup` sheet, I remove them from the output.

Comment: yes , result is as expected but it is giving error array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in C3, while i implement this code into my actual sheet , same error was displayed in whole column

Comment: @UmarArshad that's because you also had a value in `C3`, you shouldn't. Just put the whole range like this in `C2` only: `=getJobs(A2:A62, 'Data Lookup'!A2:A1795)`. I fixed it, you can look. No values below the value of the formula!

Answer (score 1):

There is a double space in **Project manager** in Cell A43 content, this is why it is not found, but you would probably have unexpected results in other occasions, because your function returns a first matched position.

Proper solution would be:

```
/** *
* @customfunction
*/


function findtitle2(text, jobs){
  jobs = jobs.flat();
  const allMatches = jobs.map( job => text.indexOf(job)>=0? job:null).filter(m=>m);

  if(allMatches.length>0){
    // sort by size
    const sortedMatches = allMatches.sort((m1,m2)=>m2.length-m1)
    // return the longest match
    return sortedMatches[0]
  } else{
    return 'Not Found'
  }
}
```